# Align pie chart to top-left of div?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a bubble chart, inside are some pie charts. Right now, I am focusing on aligning the pie charts to their respective divs. The pie charts should align to the top-left corner of their divs, but instead they're aligning to the center without reacting to my `top: 0px right: 0px attributes`. Here's my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faf06t39/):

**HTML/CSS**

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>

.whiteHat {
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

function drawSeriesChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['ID', 'Life Expectancy', 'Fertility Rate', 'Region', 'Population'],
    ['CAN', 80.66, 1.67, 'North America', 33739900],
    ['DEU', 79.84, 1.36, 'Europe', 81902307],
    ['DNK', 78.6, 1.84, 'Europe', 5523095],
    ['EGY', 72.73, 2.78, 'Middle East', 79716203],
    ['GBR', 80.05, 2, 'Europe', 61801570],
    ['IRN', 72.49, 1.7, 'Middle East', 73137148],
    ['IRQ', 68.09, 4.77, 'Middle East', 31090763],
    ['ISR', 81.55, 2.96, 'Middle East', 7485600],
    ['RUS', 68.6, 1.54, 'Europe', 141850000],
    ['USA', 78.09, 2.05, 'North America', 307007000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Correlation between life expectancy, fertility rate ' +
      'and population of some world countries (2010)',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Life Expectancy'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Fertility Rate'
    },
    bubble: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 11
      }
    }
  };
  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
    var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      // add image above every fifth element
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        var xPos = layout.getXLocation(data.getValue(i, 1));
        var yPos = layout.getYLocation(data.getValue(i, 2));

        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work', 11],
          ['Eat', 2],
          ['Commute', 2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);
        var pie = document.getElementById('piechart');
        var whiteHat = container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        whiteHat.className = 'whiteHat';
        whiteHat.style.top = yPos + 'px';
        whiteHat.style.left = xPos + 'px';
        new google.visualization.PieChart(whiteHat).draw(data2, {
          legend: {
            position: 'none'
          },
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          chartArea: {
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
          },
        });
      }
    }
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I just want to align the pie charts to the top-left corner of the div, I used a red background to show the div. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @WhiteHat For some reason, top: 0 and left: 0 don't respond at all

Answer (score 0):

I just added this CSS to make it look good:

```css
.whiteHat {
  left: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  right: auto !important;
  top: auto !important;
}
.whiteHat + .whiteHat {
  left: auto !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  top: auto !important;
}
```

The main reason I have used `!important` is to override the styles that are generated by the plugin using inline styles.

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4acLpk6L/**

**Oops**. Top left is it? Just swap the values.

```css
.whiteHat {
  left: 0 !important;
  bottom: auto !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  right: auto !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
.whiteHat + .whiteHat {
  left: auto !important;
  bottom: auto !important;
  width: 50% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmz3dka3/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do need the charts to sit in the bubble charts chart, that's why I used position absolute

Comment: @user2896120 You said top-left of the `div`?

Comment: Of their respective div, like I want the pie chart to go to the top-left of its own container (the red background)

Comment: @user2896120 That's not possible because, these charts get appended to `<body>` and not their respective `<div>`s.

Comment: Do you see how in this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q1ewrgy9/ the charts are aligned top-left of the red background? It works, but when you change the size of the chart, it does not work accordingly. Is it still not possible?